# infer the correct type during for loop

Tags: typescript, for-loop, casting, type-inference

I have an issue where i have about 40 odd actions defined, all with the same params, except each are provided with a different schema which is what's causing the issue

```
type ActionName = 'replaceText' | 'replaceImage';
type ActionTypes = 'element';
interface Action {
  objectId: string;
  name: ActionName;
}
interface Params<S> {
   element: {
      action: Action & S;
   }
}
const actions: Action[] = [{
  name: 'replaceImage',
  objectId: '123456'
}, {
  name: 'replaceText',
  objectId: 'replaceImage'
}];

class createAction<S, T extends ActionTypes> {
  run(params: Params<S>[T]) {
    console.log('paramas', params);
  }
}
type ReplaceImageSchema = {
  input: 'something'
}
type ReplaceTextSchema = {
  input: 'somethingElse'
}
const internalActions = {
  replaceImage: new createAction<ReplaceImageSchema, 'element'>(),
  replaceText: new createAction<ReplaceTextSchema, 'element'>()
}

for (const action of actions) {
  // the below fails because of conficting constituents
  internalActions[action.name].run({
    action
  })
  // the below works fine
  switch (action.name) {
    case 'replaceText': {
      const params = { action } as Params<ReplaceTextSchema>['element'];
      internalActions.replaceText.run(params)
    }
    break;
    case 'replaceText': {
      const params = { action } as Params<ReplaceImageSchema>['element'];
      internalActions.replaceImage.run(params)
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Currently i have a switch, with all the available action names however it's not ideal, hard to maintain and a lot of boilerplate/repetitive code.

`action.name` is the correct type, has the list of available action names as a string literal, Params takes a single generic of type `Schema` which is inside the interface `Schemas`

Is there a way to solve this dynamically or is the switch the only solution?

It's worth noting that i have absolutely no control over which actions are available in `actions` in the example above. They're sent via a service.

Comment: What's `element`?  What's `Params`?  (etc) Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when I take the code and paste it into a standalone IDE?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my OP with a link to a reproducible example

Comment: I'm sorry but this example isn't really making much sense to me (and it should be in plaintext as well as any external link), because I can't see how `switch` would fix it.  According to your data, your `actions` elements don't have the requisite `input` properties so it would just fail no matter what.  Are you sure this is a [mre]?

Comment: I have a hard time connecting your example to your question but the easiest fix for the error is to replace `Action & S` by `Action | S` which evaluates to all possible combinations, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz added an example of how switch solves the issue

Comment: Ehh those are type assertions, and it doesn't actually work because `input` is not present.  I think maybe we're at an impasse?  I expect a [mre] to actually demonstrate something when run, or I expect it to be pure type system stuff.  This is something else. 

Comment: I have updated my question with all you've asked for, I actually didn't even notice that input isn't actually available in my example but it's still passing compilation @jcalz

Comment: Could you provide any suggestions, even a change in how I attempting to do this? I'm kinda stuck here @jcalz

Comment: What more would you like me to add? I think the example i've provided above does suggest the issue I'm having, the "schema" is dynamically inserted based on user input, it's not something i can strongly type which is why i provide a schema (which is validated inside the run method in my actual example using zod)

Comment: As I said we are at an impasse; your example passes compilations because of type assertions, which are in your example lies you're telling the compiler.  If you're okay lying to the compiler you can just assert that `action` is the intersection type it wants like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo869w).  I'm going to disengage now unless I see an [edit] that changes the situation.  Someone else might come along and have a different opinion from me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is actually using a switch statement to exhaustively check through all the possible action types, but I still tried to reorganize the code in a way that you will have to write only one switch statement. Here is what I came up with:

```js
type ReplaceTextAction = {
  name: 'replaceAction';
  objectId: string;
  input: string
}

type ReplaceImageAction = {
  name: 'replaceImage';
  objectId: string;
  input: string
}

type Actions = ReplaceTextAction | ReplaceImageAction

type Params = {
  element: {
    action: Actions
  }
}

class ActionHandler<T extends keyof Params> {
  async run(param: Params[T]) {
    const { name } = param.action
    switch(name) {
      case 'replaceAction':
      break;
      case 'replaceImage':
      break;
      default:
      throw new Error(`Action type not handled; type = ${name}`)
    }
  }
}

const actions: Actions[] = [
  {
    name: 'replaceAction',
    input: 'something',
    objectId: '12345'
  },
  {
    name: 'replaceImage',
    input: 'somethingElse',
    objectId: '4321'
  }
]

const actionHandler = new ActionHandler()
for (const action of actions) {
  actionHandler.run({ action })
}
```